# How can I send a Data Loader to the GPU in Google Colab?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two data loaders and I am trying to send them to the GPU using `.to(device)` but this is not working.
This is the code I am using:

```
# to create a batch iterator

class MyData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.data = X
        self.target = y
        # TODO: convert this into torch code is possible
        self.length = [ np.sum(1 - np.equal(x, 0)) for x in X]
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = self.data[index]
        y = self.target[index]
        x_len = self.length[index]
        xx_len = torch.tensor(x_len)
        return {"src": x, "trg": y, "x_len": xx_len}
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)


dataset = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
                     drop_last=True,
                     shuffle=True)
test_Dataset= DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
                     drop_last=True,
                     shuffle=True)
```

I also tried to use `pin_memory = True` but this is not working too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not move the dataloader to the GPU. Instead, create batch tensors that store the data and then move these tensors to the GPU.

```py
train_dataloader = DataLoader(MyData, batch_size=BS)
...
def train(nn, optim, train_dataloader, etc...): 
    for batch in train_dataloader:
        batch = batch.to('cuda')
    ...
```

Comment: But I need my data to be in a data loader for training `train_loss = train(model, data_loader, optimizer, criterion, CLIP)`

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but inside your train function, you should iterate over the data loader where you create batches of your data. Your GPU likely will not fit all of your data at once (that is why batches are used)

Comment: @Moodhi I edited my answer to show how the function would be written